# Help identifying a capacitor

Tags: capacitor

Due to very bad SWR I have taken apart a Workman UVS-200 antenna and did a continuity test on the capacitors used for tuning. One of them seems to be bad. It is a small disc (I think ceramic capacitor) with the following markings on it:

first line - "9J"

second line - "1K?"(the letter is either U or V ... i assume V so it would read 1KV)

The cap is brown in color and also has a dot of black paint on top of it ... to be more specific the black dot is on the circumference of the disc.

All of the references I have checked for identifying a capacitor say nothing about such a marking with a single digit and a letter.

Please help in determining what capacity this thing has so I can replace it.

thanks,

D.

Comment: Please explain "continuity" and "bad". Caps should have no DC continuity. Has this one got continuity?  
 I'd guess it to be 9 pF with no other information.  
 A photo may be of great use.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure it will be a 9pF, 1kV, 5% tolerance ceramic.

See the Wiki page on [Capacitor Markings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_capacitor#Capacitor_markings) for an explanation of the commonly used markings.
Another page with similar info [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/capacitor/cap_5.html).